# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User with id= in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following this tutorial [link](https://bestror.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/validation-form-in-ruby-on-rails-with-jquery-validate/) for JQuery validations.

In the link they gave the routes as:

## in routes.rb

```
map.check_email “users/check_email”, :controller => “users”, :action => “check_email”
map.resources :users
```

As it is throwing error, I changed:

```
  match '/check_email' => 'users#check_email', :as => 'check_email'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions'}, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout" }
```

Added jquery.validate to assets/javascripts.

users_controller.rb:

```
def check_email
  Rails.logger.debug "check_email..................."
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => !@user }
  end
end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @hide_logo_section = Rails.application.config.custom.force_report_logo_accounts.include?(@user.account.name)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @user }
    end
  end
```

In sessions/new,the login form is followed by Forgot password.
app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :remote => true, :format => :json, :html => { :id => 'password_reset' }) do |f| %>
          <%= f.inputs do %>        
              <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Your email address', :input_html => {  :id => 'user_email_field',:placeholder => "Enter your email..."}%>
                          <label id="error_explanation1" class="error errorExplanation" style="margin-top:-10px;"></label>

          <% end %>
          <%= f.buttons do %>
            <%= f.commit_button :label => 'Send me that link', :button_html => {:class => 'submit button', :id => 'forgot_password_button', :disable_with => 'Wait...' }%>
          <% end %>

        <% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert('hellllllll');
  $('#password_reset').validate({
    debug: true,  
    rules: {
      'user[email]': {required: true, email: true, 
        remote:'/users/check_email' }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I am calling controller in the above script with remote.
The required and email validations are fine but it is throwing error when checking the method. Infact it is not going to the method check_email and showing id=check_email in the log.
This is my log:

> Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-04 15:36:22 +0530
>   Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML   Rendered
>   sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/home (1152.6ms)   Rendered
>   home/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)   Rendered home/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 1718ms (Views: 1315.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-04
>   15:36:24 +0530 RailsDevTweaks: Skipping ActionDispatch::Reloader hooks
>   for this request.
>
> Started GET "/users/check_email?user%5Bemail%5D=test1%40gmail.com" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-04 15:36:38 +0530 RailsDevTweaks: Skipping ActionDispatch::Reloader hooks for this request. Processing by
>   UsersController#show as JSON   Parameters:
>   {"user"=>{"email"=>"test1@gmail.com"}, "id"=>"check_email"}   User
>   Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."account_id"
>   IS NULL AND "users"."id" = ? AND (users.deleted_at IS NULL) LIMIT 1 
>   [["id", "check_email"]] Completed 404 Not Found in 331ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User with id=check_email
>   [WHERE "users"."account_id" IS NULL AND (users.deleted_at IS NULL)]:
>   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:343:in
>   `find_one'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:314:in`
>   find_with_ids'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in
>   `find'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:95:in`find'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in
>   `find'   (gem)
>   inherited_resources-1.3.1/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:44:in`
>   resource'   (gem) cancan-1.6.9/lib/cancan/inherited_resource.rb:12:in
>   `load_resource_instance'   (gem)
>   cancan-1.6.9/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in`load_resource'
>   (gem) cancan-1.6.9/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in
>   `load_and_authorize_resource'   (gem)
>   cancan-1.6.9/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in`block in
>   add_before_filter'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in
>   `_run__917766069841795016__process_action__2108608744963441679__callbacks'
>   (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in`
>   __run_callback'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in
>   `_run_process_action_callbacks'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in
>   `process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`
>   process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in
>   `block in process_action'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in`block
>   in instrument'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in
>   `instrument'   (gem)
>   activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in`
>   instrument'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in
>   `process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in`
>   process_action'   (gem)
>   activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in
>   `process_action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in`process'
>   (gem) actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in
>   `process'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in`dispatch'
>   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in
>   `dispatch'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in`block in
>   action'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in
>   `call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in`
>   dispatch'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in
>   `call'   (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in`block in
>   call'   (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'   (gem)
>   journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in`call'   (gem)
>   actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in
>   `call'   (gem)
>   meta_request-0.2.1/lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:11:in`
>   call'

Please helpActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User with id=

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your routes. Check what [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) says:

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.

When you call the URL: `/users/check_email` actually you're executing the `users#show` action.

Change your `check_email` route to something like

```
get '/users/validation/check_email', to: 'users#check_email', as: :check_email
```

and it will work.

ps: don't forget to update the url on your javascript.

Comment: I added `post '/users/validation/check_email' => 'users#check_email', :as => 'check_email'` above `devise_for :users`and `resources :users` and I also update url in script as `remote:'users/validation/check_email'`. But I am getting error as : ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/validation/check_email"):

Comment: @sachingod Change the route to `GET`, instead of `POST`... `get '/users/validation/check_email' => 'users#check_email'`...

Comment: I tried, it is not showing error but it is not going to controller. I tested it by using puts and Rails.logger.debug